# Plot : Too many ticks on X axe

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

The first loaded plot have too many ticks on X axe (see image01).

[image]

If I use the zoom action on X axe, the plot is now well loaded.

[image]

Can you give me some advise where I can search because The Plot constructor parameters seems good.

```
date_range = (735599.0, 735745.0)
x = (735610.5, 735647.0, 735647.5, 735648.5, 735669.0, 735699.0, 735701.5, 735702.5, 735709.5, 735725.5, 735728.5, 735735.5, 735736.0)
y = (227891.25361545716, 205090.4880046467, 208352.59317388065, 175462.99296699322, 98209.836461969651, 275063.37219361769, 219456.93600708069, 230731.12613806152, 209043.19805037521, 218297.51486296533, 208036.88967207001, 206311.71988471842, 216036.56824433553)
y0 = 218206.79192
x_after = (735610.5, 735647.0, 735647.5, 735701.5, 735702.5, 735709.5, 735725.5, 735728.5, 735735.5, 735736.0)
y_after = (227891.25361545716, 205090.4880046467, 208352.59317388065, 219456.93600708069, 230731.12613806152, 209043.19805037521, 218297.51486296533, 208036.88967207001, 206311.71988471842, 216036.56824433553)
linex = -39.1175584541
liney = 28993493.5251

ax.plot_date(x, numpy.array(y) / y0, color='r', xdate=True, marker='x')
ax.plot_date(x_after, numpy.array(y_after) / y0, color='r', xdate=True)
ax.set_xlim(date_range)
steps = list(ax.get_xlim())
steps.append(steps[-1] + 2)
steps = [steps[0] - 2] + steps
ax.plot(steps, numpy.array([linex * a + liney for a in steps]) / y0, color='b')
```

Thank you for your help. 
Manuel

Comment: I'm pretty sure that http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks is what you want. You can probably find usage examples in the matplotlib gallery.

Comment: When I watch get_xticks(), at first everything is fine but after call set_xlim(date_range), I have too many ticks on X axe.

Answer (score 5):

If you have too many `xtick` `labels`, so many that they are all munged together on the plot, you can reduce them using [`pyplot.xticks`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=xticks#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks).  the arguments are the points the labels apply to, the labels themselves and an optional rotation.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
y = np.arange(10000)
ticks = y - 5000
plt.plot(y)
k = 1000
ys = y[::k]
ys = np.append(ys, y[-1])
labels = ticks[::k]
labels = np.append(labels, ticks[-1])
plt.xticks(ys,labels, rotation='vertical')
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Do this with X axis dates.

Comment: @johnstamos - ?? not sure what your comment implies - the concept  is the same, you can chose a subset of the data for tick locations/labels whether they are dates or *numbers*.

Comment: @johnstamos- this Q&A is pretty old, there are a number of ways to solve the problem. For example [Figure.autofmt_xdate](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.autofmt_xdate) -  looks like a succinct way to handle this.  Maybe a new answer is needed but there are a number (numerous) of SO Q&A's dealing with this issue. .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you wanna do but is a rotation of your xticklabels sufficient for you?

```
# Add this code at the end of your script
# It will rotate the labels contained in your date range
plt.xticks(rotation=70)
```

If I test your code, I have 7 labels but the rotation argument is changed to 0 (horizontal)